# Amazon Workspaces Client not working on 22.04

Tags: openssl, aws

I have the official Amazon client, and I have been using it for years. When I upgraded to 22.04, the client began to crash on every launch. It seems to be an error with OpenSSL

```
$ ./workspacesclient              
No usable version of libssl was found
[1]    23961 IOT instruction (core dumped)  ./workspacesclient
```

I did attempt to load an older libssl with

```
$ sudo aptitude install libssl-dev
```

But that did not change the behavior in any way that I could see.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I've found a temporary workaround, although I can't say I love it. The workspaces client is using needs OpenSSL 1.x. Ubuntu 22.04 does not ship with this, nor is it readily available in the standard repos. I was able to manually install the package with

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1l-1ubuntu1.3_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./libssl1.1_1.1.1l-1ubuntu1.3_amd64.deb
```

At which point the client will detect the older library and run. Now I just need to remember to remove that package when they update so I don't have old security packages lying around.

Note: If you get a 404 error on the `wget` step, the library probably has had another version jump. Go to http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/, search for `libssl1.1_1.1.1l-1ubuntu`, and grab the link for the most recent version. (As of 5/10/2022, it's `1.3`.)

Comment: `libssl1.1_1.1.1l-1ubuntu` is no longer found at that link. Tried with `libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb` but didn't work

Comment: `libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.16_amd64.deb` worked for me.

Comment: The security subdomain doesn't have https? How ironic.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround—the `2.16` version worked for me today.

Comment: FYI the current most recent file is: `libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.17_i386.deb`

Comment: the same question here : https://repost.aws/questions/QUNJeF_ja_Suykous7EvfX5Q/aws-client-vpn-on-ubuntu-22-04

Comment: For those interested and using Ubuntu 23.04: You need to also install libicu70_70.1-2_amd64.deb from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/kinetic/amd64/libicu70/70.1-2 as per: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72365607/awsvpnclient-on-ubuntu-dissapear-crash/76365444#76365444

Comment: libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.19_amd64.deb latest

Answer (score 1):

After the download, this works:

```
sudo dpkg -i ./libssl1.1_1.1.1l-1ubuntu1.3_amd64.deb
```

I'm not sure why.

Comment: I was getting an error on install. `install: missing destination file operand after './libssl1.1_1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.20_amd64.deb'`. This worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As @feasoron wrote, the client uses an older version of the SSL lib. The impish repository has `libssl1.1` that is needed by the `workspacesclient`. The upgrade saves the old apt configuration so you can `mv /etc/apt/sources.list.distUpgrade /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sources-impish.list`. Then remove everything from it except the security repositories.

```
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security multiverse
```

After this, the old SSL library will be available to install with

```
apt update
apt install libssl1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

**CAREFUL!:**

This breaks DKMS for GPU install of Nvidia and other modules when installed on Ubuntu 23.04.

I had to do a complete re-install after installing libssl1.1, it completely broke the loading of modules for a few things including my GPU.  Even after an uninstall I had serious issues.

My gpu still worked, but only on open source drivers.  It would download and act like it installs the GPU kernel module for example.  However, it isn't actually getting loaded when you check.